# Can Python be used to read the webpage grid kind of data?

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on a third party applications.Now there are some webpages where data are in Grid. So is it possible to read such grid contents from the webpage and stored it into the excel sheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any programming. Excel has the ability to retreive data directly from HTML tables.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-HA010167227.aspx

In short:

1. Go to The data tab
2. Click "from web"
3. Navigate to your page
4. Select the table of interest.

You can then refresh it by refreshing the data connection.

If you want to scrape it yourself then you can do it with all the tags you have used in your question. Just learn all those things and the answer will then be obvious.

Comment: I have no choice without program the task. as I am writing automation script, where web page has some data in `grid` structure. But i am in `blackhole`,about to read data which are in `Grid`. After-all thanks for your suggestions - I will keep in my mind for future!